# how do you reset your program to its default configuration during runtime?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a small project I am working on which is WPF c# that moves an image.

I tried this but doesn't work

```
this.NavigationService.Refresh();
```

I use this method to change the position of the image:

```
public void Move(Image target, double newX, double newY, Int32 duration)
        {
            dispatcher.Start();
            Vector offset = VisualTreeHelper.GetOffset(target);
            var top = offset.Y;
            var left = offset.X;
            TranslateTransform trans = new TranslateTransform();
            target.RenderTransform = trans;
            DoubleAnimation anim1 = new DoubleAnimation(0, newY - top, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(duration));
            DoubleAnimation anim2 = new DoubleAnimation(0, newX - left, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(duration));
            trans.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.YProperty, anim1);
            trans.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.XProperty, anim2);



        }
```

After i move the image, i changed the image's margin by using:

```
myImage.Margin = new Thickness(newX, newY, 0, 0)
```

And what i want now is to add a button that resets all the changes in my program to its default configuration when i first loaded it BUT during runtime. So, the output is when i click the button, the image will go back to its default position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even after the animation has ended, it still effects the dependency property. Your choices are

- Set the animation's FillBehavior property to Stop
- Remove the entire Storyboard.
- Remove the animation from the individual property.

Please look at **[How to: Set a Property After Animating It with a Storyboard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970493.aspx)** for details

Comment: can you give me a sample code snippet on how to use the FillBehavior?